# how to extract values from files, compare it with a variable and send to out file

Tags: linux, bash, grep, find

I have myfolder with this files:

```
ls myfolder
filefoo filebar filefoobar
```

For example, the content of filefoo is:

```
total: 379400041
cache_object://localhost/active_requests    379400041       6778    0-13955161 0-14111309 0-12250718 0-11422369 0-11901178 0-11781835 0-12687756 0-17663930 5-110207691 6-123940805 2-39477289 0-0 0-0 0-0 0-0 0-0 0-0 0-0 0-0 0-0 0-0 0-0 0-0 0-0
bla bla bla
```

Note: the rest of the files have the same internal structure, but the numbers change

So the value I'm interested in extracting from these files is "total: number". this value is always in the first row of each file:

```
find myfolder -type f -exec awk '/^total:/{print $NF}' {} +
379400041
35402285
8589934592
```

And I should compare it with this variable:

```
max="1073741824"
```

So what I need is that if any of these values exceeds the $max variable (value > $max), it should output the file to an output list.
Example (non-functional):

```
if (( "value" > "$max" )); then
# or if [ "value" -gt "$max" ]; then
    the command to send the file to a list is missing > output.lst
 else
    echo "do nothing"
fi
```

expected output:

```
cat output.lst
filefoobar
```

Because filefoobar has 8589934592 and this value > $max

How to do that? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ max="1073741824"
$ ( cd myfolder
    for file in *
    do
        if (( `awk <$file '/^total/ {print($2)}'` > $max ))
        then echo $file
        fi
    done
) >output.lst
```

Note the use of grave accents, and that there are no spaces around the "=".

And of course there is no error checking here.