# how to exclude folders by date with find?

Tags: linux, bash, grep, find, awk

This is "myfolder":

```
tree -a 'myfolder'
myfolder
├── 20220902
│   ├── filefoo
│   └── filebar
├── 20221001
│   ├── filefoo
│   └── filebar
└── 20221015
    ├── filefoo
    ├── filebar
    └── filexyz
  etc...
```

my command:

```
find $folder/$(date +"%Y%m"*) -type f | xargs -I {} awk '/^total:/{sub(".*/", "", FILENAME); print FILENAME" "$NF}' {})
```

Problem: i need exclude weekends. How do I do it?

PD: I know that in bash/awk it is

```
%u The weekday as a decimal number (1–7). Monday is day one.
```

thanks

**Update Solved!**

I found the answer in stackoverflow [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44623201/8747573)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To filter out the weekends, you could format the name of the folder to a date format `%u`, which signifies the day of the week (by number).

Check out this example:

```
FOLDER_DATE=$(date -d '20221014' +%u)   #your folder name would go here

if [[ "$FOLDER_DATE" -eq 6 || "$FOLDER_DATE" -eq 7 ]]
then 
  echo "Weekend"
else 
  echo "Not Weekend"
fi
```

Comment: Even though your script didn't help me with "find", it did help me a lot with a variant of the same thing. thanks

Comment: Yes, in this example I only focused on the differentiation between the weekend folders and non-weekend folders.

Comment: Thank you very much. To be more specific, it helped me with this script, which also serves the same purpose as this question: https://serverfault.com/a/1112011/480349